# Can we restrict document creation on client side in firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Can we restrict document creation on the client side in firestore ? Example if User wants to create a document and save it. It will be only validated on firestore and will waste time if we have the security matrix on the client side, which can provide us access capabilities. It is just to stop regular non-hacking users, not the evil minds to save some trips to firestore.

any suggestion would be great .

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly you're trying to accomplish here. Are you aware of Firestore security rules?  https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started

Comment: Firebase doesn't provide any kind of API to do that on the client side. You'd probably have to implement it yourself